# Bucket insert fails with error code 400

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Here is the code segment:

```
Bucket newBucket = storage.buckets().insert("MyProject", new Bucket().setName("MyBucket").setLocation("US").setStorageClass("DURABLE_REDUCED_AVAILABILITY")).execute();
 } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
      System.out.println("Exception in tryCreateBucket: "+e);
      throw e;
 }
```

It throws:
Exception in tryCreateBucket:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid Value",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Value"
}
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this problem?

Thanks
/VK

Comment: Changed bucketname but am still getting the same error. Here's the code snippet & output...
System.out.println("Creating bucket, projName: "+projName+", bucketName: "+bucketName) ;try {
      Bucket createdBucket = storage.buckets().insert(projName, 
          new Bucket().setName(bucketName).setLocation("US")
        ).execute();
    } Output: Creating bucket, projName: CloudStorage, bucketName: 1904mybucketfoo2409
400 Bad Request
{"code" : 400,"errors" : [ {"domain" : "global","message" :"Invalid argument.","reason" : "invalid"} ],
  "message" : "Invalid argument."
}

Comment: How did you solve it,would you please mention solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

bucket names must be lowercase. There are a number of other restrictions as well - please see https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/bucketnaming#requirements

Comment: Changed the bucket name but am still getting the same error.  Can't seem to be able to put my finger on the root cause...

Answer (score 2):

Your project name is wrong, you need the one of the form foo-barbar-12345 that Google assigned, not the plain name that you gave it (CloudStorage)